# Need help translating C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am looking at [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815114302/http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2008/01/16/listcollectionviewcollectionview-doesnt-support-notifycollectionchanged-with-multiple-items.aspx) blog, and I am trying to translate the snippet to VB.

I'm having difficulties with this line:

```
NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handlers = this.CollectionChanged;
```

NOTE: CollectionChanged is an event of this ('this' is an override of `ObservableCollection<T>`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To *raise* the event, `OnCollectionChanged` should work fine. If you want to *query* it you have to get more abusive and use reflection (sorry, example is C# but should be virtually identical - I'm not using any language-specific features here):

```
NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler handler = (NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler)
    typeof(ObservableCollection<T>)
    .GetField("CollectionChanged", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetValue(this);
```

et voila; the handler or handlers (via `GetInvocationList()`).

So basically in your example (regarding that post), use:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnCollectionChanged(e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    If e.Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add AndAlso e.NewItems.Count > 1 Then
        Dim handler As NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler = GetType(ObservableCollection(Of T)).GetField("CollectionChanged", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(Me)
        For Each invocation In handler.GetInvocationList
            If TypeOf invocation.Target Is ICollectionView Then
                DirectCast(invocation.Target, ICollectionView).Refresh()
            Else
                MyBase.OnCollectionChanged(e)
            End If
        Next
    Else
        MyBase.OnCollectionChanged(e)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Mark, you're the winner, big time!

Answer (score 2):

Literally, it should be something like

```
Dim handlers As NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler = AddressOf Me.CollectionChanged
```

(can't tell since I don't know the exact types)

But note that you raise events in VB using `RaiseEvent`

Comment: This only works if `CollectionChanged` is the subscriber, not the event handler (which it probably is) but in this case, your second sentence applies.

Comment: It doesn't work at all, I tried this a year ago. AddressOf expects nothing but a method name.

Comment: @Shimmy: given your information, it was a valid guess. `AddressOf` works in this exact context. There’s no other direct translation of what you want.

Comment: OK, Please review the post in that blog.

Answer (score 2):

Duh. After having finally seen *and read* the blog posting you linked, here’s the answer:

In VB, you need to declare a **custom event** to override the `RaiseEvent` mechanism. In the simplest case, this looks like this:

```
Private m_MyEvent As EventHandler

Public Custom Event MyEvent As EventHandler
   AddHandler(ByVal value as EventHandler)
      m_MyEvent = [Delegate].Combine(m_MyEvent, value)
   End AddHandler

   RemoveHandler(ByVal value as EventHandler)
      m_MyEvent = [Delegate].Remove(m_MyEvent, value)
   End RemoveHandler
   RaiseEvent(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
      Dim handler = m_MyEvent

      If handler IsNot Nothing Then
          handler(sender, e)
      End If
   End RaiseEvent
End Event
```

In your case, the `RaiseEvent` routine is slightly more involved to reflect the additional logic, but the gist remains the same.

Comment: @Shimmy: I rolled back your edit; it actually introduced a nasty multithreading bug. Copying the event handler **is** important! (And `Shadows` just had no place in there.)

Comment: how can i get in to the base event then?

Comment: @Shimmy: you cannot. For whatever reason, no class can access its base class events directly. .NET just doesn’t allow that.

Comment: but if use the custom even it doesn't do anything, since the events are attached to the INotifyCollectionChanged event ignoring the custom event