# How to check which event are assigned?

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, controls

My code is as follows.

```
Control[] FoundControls = null;
FoundControls = MyFunctionToFilter(TF, c => c.Name != null && c.Name.StartsWith("grid"));
var eventinfo = FoundControls[0].GetType().GetEvents();
```

However, eventinfo gives me the list of all the controls which belongs to the grid.
Whereas there are only two events that are defined that is **KeyDown** and **Validating** in the main class.

How can I get a list of these assigned events, that is, Keydown and Validating?

Comment: You want to return ONLY Keydown and Validating events?

Comment: @Jacob Yes.... Because these are the only two events declared in the main class

Comment: do you mean "event handlers declared" instead of "two events declared"?

Comment: @Kyle is it winforms?

Comment: yes it is winform..and  in my main form i have          private void gridControl1_EditorKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {

        }

Comment: @Kyle one more question - you need to get assigned events of DataGridView only, or for any control?

Comment: Explain your real problem. Why would you want to know the available events? Why not just subscribe to the events you're interested in? This is like calling the bus company whether their buses have Diesel engines in them, while you actually just want to get from A to B.

Comment: OK ...I guess that would help a bit

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Yes only for Datagridview

Comment: Essential follow-ups: Why are you doing this ? What are you trying to achieve ? There may be something out there which solves your need as-is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) (WinForms) has a tricky model of events for components (and `DataGridView` is a component). Some events are inherited from `Control` (like `FontChanged`, `ForeColorChanged`, etc.), but all specific to component events are stored in a single [EventHandlerList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist.aspx) object, which is inherited from `Component` (BTW, events from Control are also stored there, see the update at the end of the answer). There is a protected `Events` property for that:

```
protected EventHandlerList Events
{
    get
    {
        if (this.events == null)            
            this.events = new EventHandlerList(this);            
        return this.events;
    }
}
```

And here is the way how event handlers are added for `DataGridView` events:

```
public event DataGridViewCellEventHandler CellValueChanged
{
    add { Events.AddHandler(EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCELLVALUECHANGED, value); }
    remove { Events.RemoveHandler(EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCELLVALUECHANGED, value); }
}
```

As you can see, delegate (value) is passed to `EventHandlerList` with some key value. All event handlers are stored there by key. You can think about `EventHandlerList` as a dictionary with objects as keys, and delegates as values. So, here is how you can get components' events with reflection. The first step is getting those keys. As you already noticed, they are named as `EVENT_XXX`:

```
private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCELLVALUECHANGED;
private static readonly object EVENT_DATAGRIDVIEWCELLMOUSEUP;
// etc.
```

So here we go:

```
var keys = typeof(DataGridView) // You can use `GetType()` of component object.
   .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
   .Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith("EVENT_"));
```

Next, we need our `EventHandlerList`:

```
var events = typeof(DataGridView) // or GetType()
          .GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
// Could be null, check that
EventHandlerList handlers = events.GetValue(grid) as EventHandlerList;
```

And the last step, getting the list of keys, which have handlers attached:

```
var result = keys.Where(f => handlers[f.GetValue(null)] != null)
                 .ToList();
```

That will give you the keys. If you need delegates, then simply look in the handlers list for them.

UPDATE: Events which inherited from `Control` are also stored in `EventHandlerList`, but for some unknown reason their keys have different names, like `EventForeColor`. You can use the same approach as above to get those keys and check if handlers are attached.

Answer (score 2):

According to the comments in this question showing that this is a Windows Forms related question it's almost not possible to determine assigned event handlers by iterating the list, not without reflection anyway.

The following text is from [Hans Passant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3856171/395659) on a similar question:

> Windows Forms has strong counter-measures against doing this. Most
>   controls store the event handler reference in a list that requires a
>   secret 'cookie'. The cookie value is dynamically created, you cannot
>   guess it up front. Reflection is a backdoor, you have to know the
>   cookie variable name. The one for the Control.Click event is named
>   "EventClick" for example, you can see this in the Reference Source or
>   with Reflector.

Knowing the cookie name would help you get the assigned event, but I am not sure if there is such a list with all the names which you could iterate. See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/293031/395659) which demonstrates how to get an event from one control where the cookie name is known.

Here you can find [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2130848/395659) (which still goes by using a known event name).

Comment: I don't think it's correct answer. EventInfo always will not be null

Comment: I get a list of all the events as I was getting before

Comment: @TwoMore updated answer is also **incorrect**. You can't just get fields, because in winform `EventHandlerList` is used. Why people keep upvoting incorrect answers?

Comment: Is this a winform question?

Comment: @TwoMore yes, see comments to question

Comment: @TwoMore In your mentioned example the event "MyEvent" is known beforehand..... Whereas In my case we are trying to find out which are the eventhandlers declared ..here in this case it is (Keydown and validating) but there could be more...so i dont think the solution helps

Comment: @Kyle there is other problem, see my previous comments

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use reflection to look the list of handlers?

Here is a simple console app looking at handlers hooked on the events of a serial port instance:

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void OnErrorReceived(object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e){}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serialPort = new SerialPort();

        // Add a handler so we actually get something out.
        serialPort.ErrorReceived += OnErrorReceived;  

        foreach (var eventInfo in serialPort.GetType().GetEvents())
        {
            var field = serialPort.GetType().GetField(eventInfo.Name, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField);
            if (field != null)
            {
                var backingDelegate = (Delegate)field.GetValue(serialPort);
                if (backingDelegate != null)
                {
                    var subscribedDelegates = backingDelegate.GetInvocationList();

                    foreach (var subscribedDelegate in subscribedDelegates)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(subscribedDelegate.Method.Name + " is hooked on " + eventInfo.Name);
                    }
                }          
            }                     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on Kyle comment:

> @Jacob Yes.... Because these are the only two events declared in the
>   main class – Kyle

**Events** would contain KeyDown and Validating events only.

```
        Control a = new TextBox();
        var events = a.GetType().GetEvents().Where(eventInfo => eventInfo != null && (eventInfo.Name == "KeyDown" || eventInfo.Name == "Validating"));
```

> +events.ToList()[0]   {System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler KeyDown}
>
> +events.ToList()[1]   {System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler Validating}

Comment: I didn't donwvote your answer, but it's not correct answer. OP want to define which events have handlers assigned

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I understood the issue after seeing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855985/find-all-event-handlers-for-a-winforms-control-in-net/3856171#3856171 . Thanks!